# Disabling automatic suggestions on not found page

Tags: plone

I noticed that pulling up the automatic suggestions on "The item you are lookign for is not found" page is using quite much processing power on our site.

What's the best way to disable these suggestions and just tell the user "Nothing to see here. Please go away."?

(my life would be much better without users)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [these docs](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/error-handling).